# Bundling large .rda files with package

Tags: r, package, devtools

I am currently working on a package that I want to bundle some large .rda files with (hundreds of MB). If I use devtools::load_all(), my package takes forever to load since I included the files in the /data/ dir.

Is there a way to tell R to ignore the files in /data/ until I manually load them with data(), or am I better of just putting my data into a different directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you

- create a directory `inst/optionalData/` (or another suitable name)
- add functions to load these data sets on demand

as you can rely on

```
system.files("optionalDate", "nameOfFile.rds", package="yourPackage")
```

to find it.

Comment: Hmm yes this seems like a good Workaround. It would still be more convenient to have it in data so that it can be accessed with (data)

Comment: "Wishing alone doesn't alone it so."  That feature simply does not exist in `data()`, hence the workaround.

Comment: It is not an unreasonable suggestion but you would have to create a patch to R itself and get it accepted by the R Core group.   (And apologies for typo: meant to write "wishing alone doesn't make it so".)